# Make text fit perfectly with image

Tags: html, css, image

hey guys is there a way I can make a text fit perfectly with an image like that of Netflix
https://www.netflix.com/ng/title/81067760 i already have the image but making the text fit exactly and also not covering the image is just impossible for me right now
this is my code for the image

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html lang="en" dir="ltr">
     <head>
<body style="background-color: #323232">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<picture>
<source class="mov" media="(max-width: 599px)"  srcset="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original<%=Details.poster_path%>" >
<img class = "d-block w-100 img"  src = "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original<%=Details.backdrop_path%>">
</picture>
 <div class = "details">
<h1><%=Details.title %></h1>
  <p><%=Details.release_date%></p>
     <h2><%=Details.description%></h2>
    </div>
    </head>
 </body>
</html>
```

question is how do i make the div class of details fit with the image i just need to replicate the the big image and how the text is aligned vertically to the left of the screen like that of Netflix. Check this link out https://www.netflix.com/ng/title/81067760
Hope it's more clear now thanks...

Comment: Can't figure out what exactly you want.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what netflix element you are trying to replicate, but I can show you how to align the images vertically with the .details class.

Start by wrapping a div class='container' around both the picture and div class='details' elements.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
   <html lang="en" dir="ltr">
     <head>
<body style="background-color: #323232">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta charset="utf-8">

<div class='container'>
    <picture>
        <source class="mov" media="(max-width: 599px)"  srcset="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original<%=Details.poster_path%>" >
        <img class = "d-block w-100 img"  src = "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original<%=Details.backdrop_path%>">
    </picture>
    <div class = "details">
    <h1><%=Details.title %></h1>
      <p><%=Details.release_date%></p>
         <h2><%=Details.description%></h2>
    </div>
</div>
 </head>
 </body>
</html>
```

Add the following line to the top of styles.css

```
.container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Flexbox is great for this kind of thing. Read up [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe z-index property is the property that can help you.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index

This is one of the ways to allow text to cover the image. Sorry, if I hadn't understand you correctly.

Comment: Could you add some of the code or explanation from MDN?